# UI Automation and TabControl

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, ui-automation, tabitem

I have the following Toolbar

```
<ToolBar x:Name="mainToolbar" 
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 Style="{StaticResource mainToolBarStyle}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ToolbarItems}"
                 ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource toolBarItemTemplateSelector}"
                 DataContext="{Binding}">
        </ToolBar>
```

If I put this toolbar on a Grid, I am able to interact with it using the UI coded automation test, once I put it inside a TabItem the Coded UI can not find it during playback.

just an FYI, if I use simple controls, like TextBox, ListBox, & radio buttons, I DO NOT see this problem.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a known Microsoft bug, they are working on a hotfix to be released soon.
I spoke to their support team and they sent me this article to read.

Thanks for all of you who viewed my question and tried to help.
[Decoding the Coded UI Test playback failure - "Search may have failed at ControlX as it may have virtualized children ..."](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tapas_sahoos_blog/archive/2010/12/28/decoding-the-coded-ui-test-playback-failure-quot-search-may-have-failed-at-controlx-as-it-may-have-virtualized-children-quot.aspx)